# Using Broadcom BCM4313 as AP in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless card and I'm interested in turning my laptop to an Access Point. I was following the various tutorials available on the internet to achieve this. However I seem to have hit a roadblock. While all other Broadcom wireless cards seem to work , this particular card does not run with b43 driver. Any idea how to get the AP working for this card ?

Answer (score -2):

did you try some steps to do this. the solution of this problem you can find some time in search also.

http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=make+laptop+as+access+point&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

if you have some specific issue then please post back

Comment: If you found anything you think may be helpful, please post links to it, not just to search results. Google search results change extremely quickly, plus this really doesn't answer the question at all (because it's totally unclear *what* instructions you're saying the OP should try). Furthermore, "Google it" answers have a (well-deserved) bad reputation, and answers like this are likely to be disparaged (even when posted with good intentions). And [it would be even better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize the answer(s) here, providing the links for reference.